# Disable Internet Explorer shortcut keys

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vb6, vbscript, activex

> **EDIT:** After waited a while and didn't get anything yet, I've decided 
>   to do shortcut disable thingy only for 
>   IE now. Is there a possibility to disable 
>   IE shortcut keys to access menus/print
>   etc. via vbscript?

Is it possible to disable browser shortkeys?

Because many of them are using in application. For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is using and I don't want browser to popup the print window.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I'm having the same problem and couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: @DianaAmza, I couldn't find a solution for this. IE will not allow you to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can listen for the various key combinations with javascript and disable the default behaviors. There's even a library that you can use and test [here](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/). I just tested it using google chrome and firefox in their demo textarea, and it works as you want.

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+P",function() {
    return;
});
```

This works in the browsers that I listed above, but IE will not allow you to override the default behavior in some cases.

Your only option in IE is to disable the Ctrl key entirely with something like:

```
document.onkeydown = function () { 
  if (event.keyCode == 17) alert('Ctrl Key is disabled'); 
};
```

Which is not ideal and probably not what you want, but it will work.

Comment: Getting print window on Ctrl+P :(

Comment: I've just tired by using the below "Live Execution" panel. I change the key from "Ctrl+Shift+X" to "Ctrl+P" and it showing the print window. It means the browser still listening the keys. I am using firefox 3.

Comment: There are some actions you just can't disable.

Comment: what i was doing calling an alert window and when am doing so the print window with an alert message "hello" showing up. Here the script: shortcut.add("Ctrl+P",function() { alert("hello"); return; });

Comment: Thanks Keith for the help. I've tried the shortcut.js it was look very fine at first but after a thorough test I found some issues like: Alt+M fired up and IE Command Menu also shown up. I've to disable few keys which are IE short keys. Some of them are: Ctrl+P (works fine) and Alt+M (fired up but also open home menu from Command Menu). Please, if you disabled your Command Menu you would have enable it first to see this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating an event handler for keydown event, check on the keyCode and prevent its default action if needed. However this will not work in all browsers.

An example for Firefox (canceling "Print" short key, verified):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.keyCode == 80 && oEvent.ctrlKey)
        oEvent.preventDefault();
}, false)
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Any idea something similar for IE.

Comment: No, guess there is not way to prevent shortcut in IE. But does it actually make any sense to try? User can still print or paste text by accessing the menu.

Comment: I've to disable some keys and make them in use for some other purpose. Actually, it was a requirement as the system was first written on desktop and now it is moving on to the web. And on this first phase of transformation they want users to have the same experience. The use some keys frequently for some purpose and the ctrl+p is one use.

Comment: Great, then, I guess, your users used to print with ctrl+p, so let them keeping doing that.

Comment: If the application user have to print through the application, he presumed and hit the print screen button :) This how it was work on desktop and how it have to be. You could say we just moved them from one platform to another without did any exercise on user experience as they don't want their users to feel and difference on their daily doings.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice trick to fight with IE10+, to avoid display browser menus on alt key combinations, like `Alt + F`, `Alt + H` ...

I recently used on IE11, just add an anchor with the attribute `accesskey`:`[yourKey]` on your body

```
<body>
   <a href="#" accesskey="f"></a>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onkeydown = function(e){
          console.log(e.keyCode + " alt: " + e.altKey);
          e.preventDefault();
    };
    window.onkeyup = function(e){
          console.log(e.keyCode + " alt: " + e.altKey);
          e.preventDefault();
    };
   </script>
</body>
```

Now when you press `Alt + f` the browser will not display "File popup" as usual, and will let events keydown and keyup gets to you, and not only keydown.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on similar problem, [hooking keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426585/how-to-hook-ie-keyboard-event) Below code works well to disable, except the flash object on the IE has not got the focus. Since I am trying to handle keyboard event on the flash object, this code does not work for me.

```
function hookKeyboardEvents(e) {
    // get key code
    var key_code = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;

    // case :if it is IE event
    if (window.event)
    {
        if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
            window.event.returnValue = null;
            event.keyCode = 0;
        }
    }
    // case: if it is firefox event
    else
        e.preventDefault();
}

window.document.onkeydown = hookKeyboardEvents;
```

Comment: This code prevents all key strokes and works for just firefox

Comment: you're passing in "e", not "event". so change all references to "window.event" or use "e". They should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

From you application after calling the method on Ctrl+P just make the keycode as zero.I think that will solve your problem...

```
window.event.keyCode=0;
```

this will set the keycode as zero..So when explorer checks for the keyCode it will be zero...so default function will not execute...

Try this...just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE 8. The important part is IE requires ev.returnValue to be set to false. NOTE: this only works if you have focus on some element on the document...that is, if you just load the page and hit 'ctrl-p' you'll see the print dialog. But if you click somewhere on the page, then try it, it should suppress the print dialog.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) { 

    var ev = e||window.event; 

    // Do what I want keys to do ...

    // Block browser short cuts
    if(ev.preventDefault) // non-IE browsers
        ev.preventDefault();
    else  // IE Only
        ev.returnValue = false;
};
```

Comment: did you actually test this? Because it doesn't appear to work in IE9

Comment: Yes,  I've had this in production for many years and it works fine. However,  it could be I forgot to pass in the "e" parameter above. Just edited it.  I also added a note about the fact that this solution only works when your document has focus.  If no focus on the page, the print dialog will appear. Don't think there is any way around this.