# How to hook IE keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am trying to disable browser shortcuts while user tries to press some combination of keys on the swf file. Although I can achieve this in Firefox, below code does not function in IE 8. Below code is able to hook the keyboard events if focus is not on the swf file. However, what I need is hooking keyboard events when user operates on swf file.

```
function hookKeyboardEvents(e) {

    alert("hooked key");
    // get key code
    var key_code = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;

    // case :if it is IE event
    if (window.event)
    {
        if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) {
            window.event.returnValue = null;
            event.keyCode=0;
        }       
    }
    // case: if it is firefox event
    else
        e.preventDefault();

    document[flashId].keyDown(key_code);
}

window.document.onkeydown = hookKeyboardEvents;
```

Above code never executes when focus is on swf file.

Comment: Just a correction to your code.  the shiftKey, ctrlKey, and altKey properties are available for both IE and W3C browsers.  You needn't test for window.event (an IE convention).

Comment: So you mean just e.preventDefault() will cancel the the event

Comment: I think preventDefault will work with Mozilla browsers, but not IE.  You're best served by performing conditional statements based not on which browser you see, but whether the property exists at all.  Try if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } instead of if(!window.event) { e.preventDefault(); }

Comment: What I described above is called feature/property sniffing, and is generally considered safer than assuming a browser carries with it an expected set of functionality.  Don't to this everywhere, but in places you know are browser-specific.

Comment: I tried to control as described if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); but this code generates javascript error with IE 8

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.accessKey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
```