# How to disable hotkeys on some common browsers as IE,FF, Chrome like Google docs does

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I've just try to use Google docs and I see it can disable Ctrl + S hotkeys on any browsers(IE, FF, Chrome)
So plz help me and give me some advices how to do like that. I wish I could do that on my silverlight app.
Sorry for my terrible English.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jQuery.com), you can do `event.preventDefault();`. For more information you can check [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

You can check this question [Disable Internet Explorer shortcut keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130353/disable-internet-explorer-shortcut-keys)

Hope this works for you.