# native print dialog triggering twice, for iframe and page in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

is there a way i can stop internet explorer from displaying the print dialog when the user hits Ctrl + P? I want to print only parts of the page upon Ctrl + P so i put that in an iframe and i hijacked the key combination to print its contents.

```
iframe.document.execCommand('print', false, null)
```

it works but the print dialog is triggered twice, first for the whole page and then for the iframe... i need a solution that would let the dialog get displayed for the iframe but not for the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Internet Explorer shortcut keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130353/disable-internet-explorer-shortcut-keys)

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent coverage of this here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

As for whether this is something that should be done, stackoverflow's question editor override's quite a few keys without disrupting too much (hover over the toolbar buttons).

Source: [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: thanks @IamNguele, it's a good article. it says i should bind a keypress handler too, i tried that but it doesn't work.. IE is a nightmare.
here's my code
<!-- language: lang-js -->
`componentDidMount() {`
        $(document.body).on('keypress', this.handlePrintKeys.bind(this));
        $(document.body).on('keydown', this.handlePrintKeys.bind(this));
}
handlePrintKeys(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 80 && e.type === "keydown") {
   this.printIFrame();
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation()
   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
 }
}`